# Winter Bash 2016 の帽子

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

今回の帽子の名前や取得条件など。
宗教や親しんでいる（サブ）カルチャーの違いにより理解出来ないネタも多いので、そういった点の情報、考察も歓迎致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2017/01/09 に [Say Farewell to Winter Bash 2016!](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/) にて終了が宣言されました。
統計や秘匿されていた帽子の取得条件が公開され、「ファッションショー」が行われています。

Answer (score 5):

### [公開されている一覧](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)

#### [I Am Your Father / 私はおまえの父親だ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-am-your-father)

- ask, answer, or vote on the meta site
- メタサイトで質問、回答、投票のいずれかをする

ネタ・背景: 映画「スターウォーズ」（出自にまつわる情報が meta 的という事でしょうか）

#### [Running Ragged / 激走](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/running-ragged)

- earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days
- 15日以内に3つの異なるサイト（Stack Overflow を含まない）で評価ポイントを150獲得する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [011](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/011)

- collect 11 hats
- 帽子を11個集める

ネタ・背景: 不明（十進数ではないのかも、と思いましたが取得タイミングからすると、どうやら普通に十進数の十一のようです）

#### [Snaphat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/snaphat)

- answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted
- 質問開始から30分以内に回答し、スコア3を獲得し承認される

ネタ・背景: 不明（Snapchat あたりのもじりでしょうか）

#### [First Responder / 第一応答者](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/first-responder)

- post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred
- UTCにおける年明け±12時間以内にチャットにメッセージを投稿し、それがスターを付けられる

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [What's Up, Doc? / どったのセンセー?](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/whats-up-doc)

- earn reputation by contributing to Stack Overflow documentation
- Stack Overflow documentation への貢献で評価を獲得する

ネタ・背景: バッグス・バニーの口癖の Doc(tor) と Documentation をかけた物

#### [Fiery / 熱烈](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/fiery)

- post five answers that each get a score of at least 3
- スコア3以上の回答を5つ投稿する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Lifesaver / 救い主](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/lifesaver)

- answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge that gets accepted
- [閑古鳥バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed)を獲得している質問に回答し、承認される

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Mmmm Bacon / おお、ベーコンよ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/mmmm-bacon)

- ask, answer, or vote on December 30th
- 12月30日に質問、回答、投票のいずれかをする

ネタ・背景: シンプソンズのホーマーの台詞（ベーコンが大好物との事ですが、12月30日と関連があるかは解りません）

#### [The NeverEnding Story / はてしない物語](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/the-neverending-story)

- create or update at least two items in your Stack Overflow Developer Story
- あなたの Stack Overflow Developer Story に2つ以上のアイテムを作成または更新する

ネタ・背景: エンデの小説、あるいはそれを元にした映画

#### [925](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/925)

- earn a silver badge
- 銀バッジを獲得する

ネタ・背景: 925は（高品位と見なされる銀素材の）銀の含有率を指す

#### [Philantropist / 慈善家](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/philantropist)

- Award a bounty, to someone else, on the last day of hats
- 帽子の最終日に、自分以外へ bounty（[お礼](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)）を授与する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Abominable / 非道](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/abominable)

- participate in successfully closing or deleting a question
- 質問のクローズまたは削除の達成に加担する

ネタ・背景: 帽子の形状であるイエティ（雪男）は "abominable snowman" とも言う

#### [Third Time's A Charm / 三度目の魅了](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/third-times-a-charm)

- hit the reputation cap on three different days
- 別々の日に3回、評価の上限（[200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)）に達する

ネタ・背景: "Third time's a charm" は「三度目の正直」と同じ意味合いのことわざ

#### [Just Here for the Hat / 帽子のために居るだけ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/just-here-for-the-hat)

- own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats
- サイト（の利用者）全体で20種類以上の帽子が獲得されており、あなたもそのサイトで何らかの帽子を持っている

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Search You Must / 検索せよ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/search-you-must)

- use the site's search functionality on 3 consecutive UTC days
- サイトの検索機能を3日間（UTC に基づく）連続して使用する

ネタ・背景: スターウォーズシリーズのヨーダのせりふは "you must" を含む物が多い

#### [Bûche de Noël / クリスマスケーキ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/b%C3%BBche-de-no%C3%ABl)

- ask, answer, or vote on December 25th
- 12月25日に質問、回答、投票のいずれかをする

ネタ・背景: "Bûche de Noël" はケーキの一種で「クリスマスの薪」の意

#### [Cutting the Cord / 紐切り](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/cutting-the-cord)

- vote on seven questions or answers using the Android or iOS app
- Android または iOS のアプリを使用して7つの質問または回答に投票する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Polymath / 博学者](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/polymath)

- post at least one well-received answer on three different sites during Winter Bash (not including Stack Overflow)
- Winter Bash 中の3つの異なるサイト（Stack Overflow を含まない）で1つ以上の評判のよい回答を投稿する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Epiphany / 公現祭](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/epiphany)

- La Befana vien di notte con le scarpe tutte rotte
  [post or vote on January 6th]
- 真夜中、べファーナがボロ靴を履いてやってくる（イタリア語）
  [1月6日に投稿または投票をする]

ネタ・背景: 上記イタリア語のわらべ歌の「ベファーナ」とは、キリスト教の祝日である公現祭（1月6日）の前夜に訪れ、良い子にはキャンヂィーとプレゼントを、悪い子には炭を、靴下に入れるという魔女のこと

#### [Hero of Questions / 質問の英雄](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/hero-of-questions)

- edit a closed question (that you did not participate in closing) that gets reopened after your edit
- クローズ済みの（あなたがクローズに関与していない）質問を編集し、その質問が再オープンされる

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [I Have A Little Dreidel / 僕は小さなコマを持っている](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-have-a-little-dreidel)

- ask, answer, or vote on any of the days of Chanukah starting December 24-Jan 1
- ハヌカー期間中（12月24日〜1月1日）に質問、回答、投票のいずれかをする

ネタ・背景: "I Have A Little Dreidel" という歌は、ユダヤ教の年中行事であるハヌカーで遊ばれる Dreidel（ドレイドル）という木製の独楽について歌った物

#### [Maverick / 一匹狼](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/maverick)

- answer +5 a -3 question that goes to +3
- -3の質問に回答し、+3にする？（「+5」の意味が解りませんでした）

ネタ・背景: 帽子の形状がアメリカ海軍を思わせる所があり、だとすると映画「トップガン」における主人公のコールサイン "Maverick（マーベリック）" とかかっているのかもしれない

#### [Egoist / 利己主義者](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/egoist)

- ask a question and answer it yourself, with both posts getting a score of 3
- 質問してそれに自分自身で回答し、その両方の投稿ともスコア3を獲得する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [Amped Up / アゲアゲ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/amped-up)

- share a link to a question on social media that gets 5 clicks
- ソーシャルメディアで質問へのリンクを共有し、それが5回クリックされる

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [24](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/24)

- earn a gold badge
- 金バッジを獲得する

ネタ・背景: ほぼ純金である事を指す金の含有率 "k24" から

#### [Loungin' Around / ごろごろ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/loungin-around)

- post a question using the Android or iOS app that earns you the Nice Question badge
- 質問を Android か iOS のアプリで投稿し、[いい質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question)のバッジを獲得する

ネタ・背景: 特になし？

#### [No Longer Grinchy / もうグリンチってない](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/no-longer-grinchy)

- participate in successfully reopening or undeleting a question
- 再オープンか削除の阻止に参加して、それが成功する

ネタ・背景: "Grinchy" はスースの絵本「いじわるグリンチのクリスマス」あるいはそれを元にした映画により、意地悪の代名詞となった "Grinch" が形容詞化した語（だと思います）

Answer (score 3):

公開されてないものです。[参考](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/332584)

### 180°

[image: 180]

> クローズして、編集して、再オープンする。

## This Is Fine

[image: 元気]

## Where in the world

[image: Moon][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> 冬至(winter solstice)にアクティブな人。この時期に投票、投稿をすれば獲得できる。

## Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it

[image: Taco]

> 投稿にコメントせずに、1日(UTC)で5つの投稿を編集、或いは編集の提案を行う

## Elementary

[image: Element]

> 三年以上前の投稿を5つ編集する。

## blue in the face

[image: blue]

> Secret Hat Hint #1: Blue In the Face. 10 is a beautiful number - [bluefeet♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/bluefeet)　10は美しい数字だ。

## The Hatter

[image: Madhatter]

> 不明…

Comment: blue in the faceはbluefeetさんのアイコンに似てます。

Comment: 遅ればせながら、[ファッションショー出場](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/)お祝い申し上げます。

Comment: @mjy ありがとうございます！確かに、出場してますね(MadHatterとして)。

Comment: The Hatterでした…　正式名称じゃない