# ❄️ Winter Bash 2019 の帽子リスト ❄️

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

[image: Winter Bash 2019 のロゴです]

今年も帽子のイベント **Winter Bash** が Stack Exchange で開催されます。Winter Bash では特定の条件を満たすことで**帽子**を手に入れることができます。手に入れた帽子は、期間限定で被ることもできます！

Winter Bash 2019 を楽しむために、帽子の情報について教えてください！

#### 参考

- [Winter Bash 2019 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339891/314875) -- Stack Exchange
- [Winter Bash 2018 の帽子リスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2881/14055) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2017 の季節です](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2620/14055) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2016 の帽子](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2387/14055) --スタック・オーバーフロー

Comment: [I just earned a New Year's hat on Dec 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339911/341401)

Comment: [This star on the warm welcome hat looks like a communist symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340512/341401)

Answer (score 5):

## 公開されている帽子

#### Scarf Ace

[image: Scarf Ace]

条件: [師匠](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru)バッジを獲得する
背景: 『スカーフェイス』

---

#### Glasses With A Number On Top

[image: Glasses With A Number On Top]

条件: 年の変わり目 (1月1日 0:00 UTC ±12h) にチャットで☆をもらう
背景: よくあるニューイヤー眼鏡

---

#### Just Jesting

[image: Just Jesting]

条件: 10件のプラス票コメント
背景: 道化師帽子

---

#### The Milliner

[image: The Milliner]

条件: 11個の帽子を集める
背景: ???

---

#### Hero Of Time

[image: Hero Of Time]

条件: 午後7時に質問（どのタイムゾーンでも良い）
背景: 『ゼルダの伝説』のリンク

---

#### Werewolf Hunter

[image: Werewolf Hunter]

条件: メインサイトまたはメタで古い質問3件を編集
背景: ???

---

#### Rep Hunter

[image: Rep Hunter]

条件: 1日で5つの承認された回答
背景: Stack Exchange ウェブサイトの信用度アイコン

---

#### Cosmic Brain

[image: Cosmic Brain]
条件: [いい回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer)バッジを獲得
背景: ???

---

#### Fashionable

[image: Fashionable]
条件: 質問の閲覧回数が計9000回
背景: ファッショニスタ

---

#### Red Baron

[image: Red Baron]

条件: -3の質問に回答し、後に+3の質問になり、回答は+5
背景: ???

---

#### Foot of the Rainbow

[image: Foot of the Rainbow]

条件: どこかのサイトで[金バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold)を獲得
背景: ユニコーン（空想上の生き物）

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

条件: 12月21日の世界のどこかで質問、回答または投票した（バッジは1つだけ獲得できます）
背景: ???

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

条件: 12月21日の世界のどこかで質問、回答または投票した（バッジは1つだけ獲得できます）
背景: ???

---

#### Snaphat

[image: Snaphat]

条件: 30分以内に回答し +3票投じられ承認された
背景: Snapchat の口から虹が出るエフェクト

---

#### Philantropist

[image: Philantropist]

条件: 帽子の最終日に、誰かにお礼を授与した
背景: 慈善家

---

#### Bûche de Noël

[image: Bûche de Noël]

条件: 12月25日に質問、回答または投票した
背景: ???

---

#### Amazing Grace

[image: Amazing Grace]

条件: メタサイトまたはメインサイトで[銀バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=silver)を獲得した
背景: COBOL の開発者[グレースホッパー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9B%E3%83%83%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC)と讃美歌『アメイジング・グレイス』を掛けている。帽子はグレースホッパーの写真から。

---

#### Living in the Future

[image: Living in the Future]

条件: Winter Bash 以前に投稿した質問に自分で回答し、スコア+5に達した
背景:『Back to the Future』の消えかかる写真

---

#### Silencium

[image: Silencium]

条件: 一週間通報されなかった質問をした
背景: ???

---

#### Shiver Me Timbers

[image: Shiver Me Timbers]

条件: スコアが 2以上のすでに承認された回答を、少なくとも 2以上上回るスコアの回答を投稿した
背景: パイレーツ‍☠️語

---

Answer (score 4):

## シークレット帽子

参考: [MSEの投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339894/341401)

#### The Merlin

[image: The Merlin]

> 条件: 「ひらめき」バッジを獲得。
>  背景: マーリンは偽史『ブリタニア列王史』に登場する魔術師

---

#### Warm Welcome

[image: Warm Welcome]

> 条件: そのユーザーの最初の投稿を +1 投票する。
>  背景: ???

---

#### Universe Brain

[image: Universe Brain]

> 条件: 「会心の回答」バッジを取得。
>  背景: ???

---

#### This Is Fine

[image: This Is Fine]

> 条件: お礼がついている質問に回答して +1 投票をもらったものの、お礼の対象にならなかった。回答はお礼がついている期間に投稿されねばなりませんが、Winter Bashの期間中で無くても良い。
>  背景: ???

---

#### 007

[image: 007]

> 条件: スコア +7 以上の回答を投稿し、質問にも回答にもコメントがゼロ件。
>  背景: 『007』のボンドスーツ

---

#### Blue in the Face

[image: Blue in the Face]

> 条件: ???
>  背景: ???

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image: Propel Thyself]

> 条件: ひとつのサイトで 3 つのシークレット帽子を手に入れる。
>  背景: ???

---

#### Rubber Ducky

[image: Rubber Ducky]

> 条件: どこかのサイトで質問の「破棄」ボタンを使う。帽子をもらうまでに3時間かかる。質問の下書きを書いて7日間放っておき自動削除されることによっても得られる。
>  背景: ???

---

#### 180°

[image: 180°]

> 条件: 質問のクローズに投票し、クローズされてから最初に質問を編集し、再オープンに投票する。
>  背景: ???

---

#### Mother of Dragons

[image: Mother of Dragons]