# Winter Bash 2020 の帽子リスト 

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

[image]

帽子の季節です！　2020 年も Stack Exchange の帽子の季節が[やってきました](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/)。皆さんもう帽子は被りましたか？　何やら今年は国際色豊かな帽子が数多くあるようです。

また、今年もサイトごとに帽子の数で[競っています](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)。帽子コンテストをやっているサイトもあります。楽しみですね。

ところで帽子は何種類あるのでしょうか。どんな条件で解放されるのでしょうか。一覧が欲しいです、教えてください！

#### 参考

- [Winter Bash 2020 hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915)   -- Stack Exchange
- [Winter Bash 2020 hat names & references explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358178) -- Stack Exchange
- [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 の帽子リスト ❄️](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3144) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2018 の帽子リスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2881) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2017 の季節です](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2620) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2016 の帽子](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2387) --スタック・オーバーフロー

Comment: Tips: トリガーとなるアクションを起こしてから帽子を獲得できるまで、若干のタイムラグがあります。着替えた後はしばらく同じ帽子を被ったままにしておくとよいかもしれません (頻繁に着替えると取りこぼす可能性も)。

Answer (score 3):

## シークレット帽子

補足：[MSE の回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917) を随時和訳しています。

---

#### Vexillologist

[image]

**（未解明）**

帽子獲得のロジックに[バグがあり](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56450361#56450361)、本来この帽子を獲得すべきでないユーザーでも獲得できてしまっていました。2020-12-16 13:18 (UTC) より前に獲得されたすべての帽子は既に取り消されており、本来獲得すべきであった人のみに与えられています。

---

#### Samovar

[image]

> 自己回答を投稿し、質問も回答も +2 以上の投票を得る。ただしサイトごとのメタサイトでは機能しません。

---

#### Quarantine Hair

[image]

> どこかのサイトで帽子を被る。

---

#### Take This!

[image]

> [ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour) を受けて [準備万端バッチ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) を得る。

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image]

> これ以外のシークレット帽子を 1 つのサイトで 3 つ獲得する。

---

#### Cordovan

[image]

> 質問者によって 1 日以内に編集された質問にコメントする。

---

#### Balalaika

[image]

**（未解明）**

帽子獲得のロジックに[バグがあり](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555#56467555)、本来この帽子を獲得すべきでないユーザーでも獲得できてしまっていました。2020-12-17 21:04 (UTC) より前に獲得されたすべての帽子は既に取り消されており、本来獲得すべきであった人のみに与えられています。

---

#### Disciple

[image]

**（未解明）**

帽子獲得のロジックに[バグがあり](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555#56467555)、本来この帽子を獲得すべきでないユーザーでも獲得できてしまっていました。2020-12-17 21:04 (UTC) より前に獲得されたすべての帽子は既に取り消されており、本来獲得すべきであった人のみに与えられています。

---

#### Warm Welcome

[image]

> そのユーザーの最初の投稿にプラス投票する。

---

#### Mariachi

[image]

> 3 回お気に入りされた投稿をチャットでする。

---

#### Movin' on Up

[image]

> 他の回答より投票スコアが小さいものの承認された回答をする。質問自体の投票スコアもプラスである必要があります。

---

#### Give a Leg Up

[image]

---

#### This is Fine

[image]

> 懸賞金が提示され、かつまだ懸賞金が渡されていない質問に回答し、この帽子の計算スクリプトが実行されたときに[投票スコアがプラスになっている](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340757)。回答は懸賞金がかかっている期間に行われる必要がありますが、Winter Bash の期間中である必要はありません。自己回答の場合も、その投票スコアがプラスで、かつ誰かに懸賞金を渡した場合はこの帽子が獲得できます。

---

#### Cruse of Oil

[image]

---

#### Eliza Doolots

[image]

---

#### Right to run fast and jump for joy

帽子ではありませんが、シークレットな機能なのでここに書いておきます。この「権利」を得た上で Winter Bash のサイトにログインすると、とあるゲームにアクセスできるようになります。もしこの「権利」を得ていると、他の帽子同様にサイトのトップバーにある Winter Bash 用のドロップダウン・メニューに表示されます。

> この権限は Social Distancing の帽子を被ると獲得できます。

Answer (score 1):

## 公開されている帽子

#### Social Distancing (Main)

[image: Social Distancing (Main)]

メインサイトの質問ページを訪れる。Meta Stack Exchange も含みます。モバイルアプリで訪れたり、タグのページを訪れたり、レビューキューを見たりしても OK です。

---

#### Social Distancing (Meta)

[image: Social Distancing (Meta)]

メタサイトの質問ページを訪れる。Meta Stack Exchange も含みます。モバイルアプリで訪れたり、タグのページを訪れたり、レビューキューを見たりしても OK です。

---

#### TikTop

[image: TikTop]

速攻で回答が得られた質問をする

---

#### Soapbox

[image: Soapbox]

メタで議論を開始する

---

#### Edward

[image: Edward]

好奇心バッジを獲得する

---

#### Hanafuda

[image: Hanafuda]

プラススコアの投稿を 5 つする

---

#### Backlog

[image: Backlog]

古い無回答の質問に答える

---

#### Snaphat

[image: Snaphat]

30 分以内に回答し +3 票を得て承認される

---

#### Rep Hunter

[image: Rep Hunter]

1 日の内に投票がプラスの回答を 10 個する

---

#### Kitsune

[image: Kitsune]

質問の再オープンに投票し、回答する

---

#### I Wish to Subscribe

[image: I Wish to Subscribe]

Meta Stack Exchange で [feature-request] タグの質問にプラス投票する

---

#### Bûche de Noël

[image: Bûche de Noël]

12 月 25 日に投稿または投票する

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

12 月 21 日に投稿または投票する

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

12 月 21 日に投稿または投票する

---

#### Happy New Year

[image: Happy New Year]

1 月 1 日 0:00 (UTC) から前後12時間の間にチャットをしてスターをもらう

---

#### Milliner

[image: Milliner]

11 個の帽子を集める

---

#### Bouncer

[image: Bouncer]

3 回クローズ票レビューキューのレビューをする

---

#### Doorman

[image: Doorman]

3 回再オープン票レビューキューのレビューをする

---

#### Chimney Sweep

[image: Chimney Sweep]

3 回編集提案レビューキューのレビューをする

---

#### Wa-boushi

[image: Wa-boushi]

師匠バッジを獲得する

---

#### Carmen

[image: Carmen]

編集の提案が承認される

---

#### Gimme Space

[image: Gimme Space]

新しいコミュニティに参加する

---

#### Flashlight

[image: Flashlight]

ダークモードを試す

---

#### Comin' Up Roses

[image: Comin' Up Roses]

5 つの回答 がついた +5 スコアの質問をする

---

#### Matryoshka

[image: Matryoshka]

クローズ投票もしくは再オープン投票を 10 回する

---