# クールな帽子セレクション 2020 

Tags: 討議, winter-bash

素敵な帽子の着こなし画像をどうぞこちらに共有してください。どのようなスタイルでも大歓迎です！

今年のファッショニスタ一番乗りはこちらのお二人だったのではないでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[Winter Bash 2020 の帽子リスト👒 🎩](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3459/14055) -スタック・オーバーフロー
[Show off your hats! (2020 Edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357952/314875) -Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2):

[image: Moon]

Answer (score 1):

[image: kunifさんのマスクです]

Answer (score 1):

kawaii!

[image: sayuriさんが耳当てを被ってらっしゃるところです]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: モデレータの皆様今年も大変お世話になりました]

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow のサイトをみていたら、今年は新しい自分に出会うために髪型を変えてみるのも良いのではないか、と思えてきました 
[image: わたしと小鳥とすずと]

Answer (score 0):

sugoi!
[image: My first Nintendo]