# Winter Bash 2021 の帽子リスト  

Tags: 討議, winter-bash

今年も残すところあとわずか。ということは…そう、帽子の季節です！Winter Bash 2021 ではいつものように公開されている帽子とシークレット帽子があります。特定の条件を満たすことで帽子を手に入れることができ、手に入れた帽子は期間限定で被ることができます。

Winter Bash 2021 を楽しむために、帽子の情報について教えてください！

#### 参考

- [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List 😷 🎓](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372999/314875) -- Stack Exchange
- [Winter Bash 2020 の帽子リスト👒 🎩](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3459/14055) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 の帽子リスト ❄️](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3144) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2018 の帽子リスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2881) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2017 の季節です](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2620) --スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2016 の帽子](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2387) --スタック・オーバーフロー

Answer (score 4):

## 公開されている帽子

#### Clockwork

[image: Clockwork]

同じ時間に投票

---

#### Tenacious

[image: Tenacious]

古い質問への自己回答

---

#### Rep hunter

[image: Rep hunter]

1日に10の回答を投稿

---

#### Spotless

[image: Spotless]

素晴らしい初質問を投稿

---

#### Consensus

[image: Consensus]

再オープンレビューの検証

---

#### Rapport

[image: Rapport]

クローズレビューの検証

---

#### Harmony

[image: Harmony]

編集の提案レビューの検証

---

#### Hi5

[image: Hi5]

1日に5つの承認済み回答

---

#### Rep cap

[image: Rep cap]

信用度の上限

---

#### Soapbox

[image: Soapbox]

メタで討議を開始

---

#### Plus 44

[image: Plus 44]

良い質問への良い回答

---

#### I voted

[image: I voted]

どこかに投票

---

#### Glare reducers

[image: Glare reducers]

ハイコントラストやダークモード機能のお試し

---

#### Starfish

[image: Starfish]

2つの好評コメント

---

#### Gem detector

[image: Gem detector]

+50プラス票で質問がオープン

---

#### Gem finder

[image: Gem finder]

+30プラス票で質問がオープン

---

#### Gem watcher

[image: Gem watcher]

+10プラス票で質問がオープン

---

#### Sunrise

[image: Sunrise]

初コミュニティで質問

---

#### New moon

[image: New moon]

新月に質問を投稿

---

Comment: .svg画像を.pngに変更する必要があると思います。

Answer (score 2):

## シークレット帽子

**Thought Bubble**

[image: Thought Bubble]

> チャットで会話：1日に1つの部屋にて少なくとも5つの異なるブロックでチャットメッセージを[送信]する

---

**Spotting Scope**

[image: Spotting Scope]

未解明

---

**Detective**

[image: Detective]

> 特定のサイトで3つのシークレット帽子を獲得する

---

**Monologue**

[image: Monologue]

> プラススコアの質問を投稿して回答を得る

---

**Dialogue**

[image: Dialogue]

> 自己回答にコメント - 質問はプラススコア

---

**Trialogue**

[image: Trialogue]

> 自己回答にコメントした後に回答が編集される　- 質問はプラススコア

---

**Quadalogue**

[image: Quadalogue]

未解明

---

**Defender of the Unicorn**

[image: Defender of the Unicorn]

> Meta Stack Exchange で質問を投稿し、後にタグが[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)に付け替えられる

---

**E-pic**

[image: E-pic]

未解明

---

**"Game hat"**

Hat with ID -100, referenced in the `wummer-hats.js` source file.

未解明

---

**One buried penny**

[image: One buried penny]

未解明

---

**Two buried pennies**

[image: Two buried pennies]

未解明

---

**Three buried pennies**

[image: Three buried pennies]

未解明

---

**Matryoshka**

[image: Matryoshka]

> +5スコアの質問を投稿し、+5以上の回答を得る

---

**Satellite view**

[image: Satellite view]

未解明

---

**Cleanup**

[image: Cleanup]

未解明

---

**Helping finger**

[image: Helping finger]

> 初めての投稿にプラススコアのコメントを3つ投稿する

---

**Helping hand**

[image: Helping Hand]

> 初めての投稿にプラススコアのコメントを2つ投稿し、コメントの後に元の投稿者が質問を編集

---

**Helping heart**

[image: Helping heart]

未解明

---

**Helping arm**

[image: Helping arm]

> 新規ユーザーの初めての投稿にコメントし、新規ユーザーが投稿を編集し、後に+2スコア以上になる（クローズされていない、再オープンはOK）

---

**Kitsune**

[image: Kitsune]

> 質問の再オープンに投票し、再オープン後に回答しプラススコア

---

**Manual key**

[image: Manual Key]

> メタサイト（MSEを含む）の投稿の本文から何かをコピーし、質問のタグは[討議](/questions/tagged/%e8%a8%8e%e8%ad%b0)

---

**Slow Trickle**

[image: Slow Trickle]

> 4つの異なる日に自分の回答または質問にプラス票を投じられる